# Rails Engine Configuration Block returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this configuration block and its returning nil for some reason.

```
module MyModule

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :username,:password

    def initialize
      @username = nil
      @password = nil
      @templates = 'my value'
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `MyModule::Configuration.templates` I get nil. I would expect to get `'my value'`

Answer (score 2):

Have you just missed the `attr_accessor` for it?

```
attr_accessor :username, :password, :templates
```

But I think you mean you should call `MyModule::Configuration.new.templates`